# Backbone-Forms submitButton option doesn't work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-forms

In Backbone-Forms' [docs](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#options) it's mentioned that you can pass a submit button to the form.

> submitButton {String} 
>   If provided, creates a submit button at the
>   bottom of the form using the provided text

I did so but it doesn't work.

```
form = new Form({
    fieldsets:[
        {legend:'PART1', fields:['title', 'content', 'email']},
        {legend:'PART2', fields:['country', 'sport']}],
    submitButton: 'SEND',
}).render();
```

[Some lines in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elhoucine9/o7scwy1a/8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Backbone-Forms you are using and referencing in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elhoucine9/o7scwy1a/8/) example haven't `submitButton` feature yet.

Read the master changelog and you will see. As I saw from official repo this is a new feature and currently available only on master branch. You can download and use that one [from official repo](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms).

Here is the link of the [latest one](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms/blob/master/distribution/backbone-forms.js).